# Why SVG in .svg file scales but when it's in .html file it won't?

Tags: html, css, svg, adobe-illustrator

I have generated a simple [SVG file](https://amigoow.github.io/overview.svg) from Adobe Illustrator. When I open this .svg file in browser and I resize the browser window it is responsive to both height and width [desired behaviour].

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 1400 778" enable-background="new 0 0 1400 778" xml:space="preserve">

    ----SVG CODE---

</svg>
```

But when same SVG is inlined inside [HTML file](https://amigoow.github.io/overview.html) it is only responsive to width of browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Overview</title>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>


<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 1400 778" enable-background="new 0 0 1400 778" xml:space="preserve">

   ----SVG CODE---
</svg>



</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here to make it responsive to height and width of the browser window?

Comment: You are required to post your markup here within your question, not any third party site which can change or go dead and help no one in the future.  [mcve]

Comment: @Rob just updated my question. The files are linked to my own github repo just to show the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set an explicit height and width of 100% on the html, body and svg elements so that they all fill the display.

```css
html, body, svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Overview</title>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>


<svg viewBox="0 0 1400 778" xml:space="preserve">

   <rect width="1400" height="778" fill="red"/>
</svg>



</body>
</html>
```